# How to find a document in mongoose by child property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this Person and User models in my project:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

const schema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', schema);
```

and

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({

    person: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Person',
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

As we can see, a User has a reference to Person. I'm trying to find one User by either his email or by name of his Person. I tried many different approaches, like this:

```
exports.getUserByPersonNameOrEmail = async (uservalue) => {
    var user = await User.findOne({
        $or: [
            {"person.name": uservalue},
            {email: uservalue}
        ]
    });
    return user;
};
```

I also read about using the `$elemMatch` command, but it seems that it is used for documents with an array of children, instead of a specific child.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use mongoose populate and its `match` step during `populate`:

```
var user = await User.findOne({}).populate({
  path: 'person',
  match: { name: uservalue }, 
  select: 'name -_id'
}).exec()
```

You can read more [about it here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions). The idea basically is that you have to `populate` the actual references to `person` in your use model in order to query them. `match` applies a filter while they are being populated  etc.

Comment: Sorry for delay in my response. What this query does is get the first User in MongoDB, and then populate its person ONLY if it matches its name with uservalue. What I actually want to do is find a User which its person has a match between person.name and uservalue, instead this code where it will get the first row in User table/document and return it.

Comment: According to [this link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4043#issuecomment-207559230), it's impossible to do a query by a child property, while the `.populate()` only does is populate the child properties if it matches the given criteria